# The command 'yarn --v' also initiates 'yarn install' and installs packages automatically. Why is this happening?

Tags: git-bash, yarnpkg

The git bash session is as shown below. I entered the command 'yarn --v', and everything else camp up. What is the issue?

Git bash session

[image: Git bash session.png]

Answer (score 4):

The command should be `yarn -v` or `yarn --version`
As you ran yarn with incorrect command line arguments the current implementation of Yarn silently ignores them.

The Yarn documentation states that running yarn with no args will run `yarn install`.
This is why it starts to install